# React Js + bootstrap bilingual application rtl issue

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4

I'm building a bilingual react js application (Arabic & English) everything is working fine until I add bootstrap. If I import bootstrap library rtl dir not working, if I import bootstrap rtl library ltr dir not working. Any suggestions to solve this problem?

bootstrap v4.2.1, react 16.8. I meant by not working that page direction not changing in case of I change the language in both cases (if I import bootstrap library page direction always appears ltr. Also if I import bootstrap rtl library page direction always appears rtl). If I totally remove bootstrap import both languages works correctly (rtl dir in Arabic ltr in English). No errors rtl issue is common in bootstrap, so they created bootstrap rtl

Thanks

Comment: Hey! Please provide some bit more context: some error messages, versions of Bootstrap and any other libs that you're using. What do you mean by `not working`? Please describe it here, so the people can provide you a targeted help.

Comment: bootstrap v4.2.1, react 16.8. I meant by not working that page direction not changing in case of i change the language in both cases (if I import bootstrap library page direction always appears ltr. Also if I import bootstrap rtl library page direction always appears rtl). If I totally remove bootstrap import both languages works correctly (rtl dir in Arabic ltr in English). No errors rtl issue is common in bootstrap, so they created bootstrap rtl.